# How to Use FB API Graph within C# Desktop Application

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, desktop-application, facebook-c#-sdk

I just started a projects that need to be created with C# Desktop Application using Visual Studio 2008 (.NET 3.5).

Now I really don't understand where I have to start. I just start to "googling" and found that there tools C# FACEBOOK SDK. But after I read more, now it's not supported from Facebook. So, please anyone can help me.

**MY GOAL** : To read facebook timeline of user from a desktop application.

Can I user any other SDK that supported ?
Or maybe can I use Facebook PHP SDK ?

Your help really appreciated.

Thankyou

Comment: An SDK does not have to be officially endorsed by Facebook. (And basically you don’t _need_ any SDK at all, because all you need to communicate with the API is the ability to make HTTP requests. But of course SDKs usually make this easier.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Facebook SDK. Its possible to use, connect, post, read informations and anothers tasks.

To start, have some information at web:

1. Open NuGet manager at Visual Studio and ask for Facebook SDK.
2. Read Facebook Developers Starters Guide: https://developers.facebook.com/
3. When we start a FB app, a token is necessary. Read about this at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register

I hope this helps to start .